# Define function signature for a class member in Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to specify the signature of a function used as a class field.
Here is an example:

```
class Space<PointType>
{
    // num distance(PointType, PointType); This does not work
    final distance; // This works but dystance types are not defined 

    Space(num this.distance(PointType, PointType));     
}
```

I know I can use typedef to define a callback interface. However this does not seem to work within generics.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics with `typedef`. In your case :

```dart
typedef num ComputeDistance<E>(E p1, E p2);
class Space<PointType> {
  final ComputeDistance<PointType> distance;
  Space(this.distance);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `typedef` to declare the signature of a function used in a class field.  I am not entirely sure I follow your specific example, so I'll keep the discussion generic.

Here is the syntax for using a `typedef`:

```dart
typedef functionReturnType nameOfTypedef(ParamType paramName);
```

Here is a concrete example:

```dart
typedef String MyFuncType(int x, int y);
```

This example defines `MyFuncType` to return a `String` and take two `int` arguments.

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyFuncType func; // Matches a func that returns a String and take 2 int arguments.
  ...
}
```

You can read a fuller discussion about using `typedef`s at https://github.com/dart-lang/cookbook/blob/basics/basics.asciidoc#using-typedef-to-declare-a-function-signature.